# Styling the actual first child (not just first found child)

Tags: css

I want to negate the leading `<br>` in a `<p>` tag, if it exists - and `:first-child` doesn't fit the bill. Any ideas?

This `<br>` must be caught. I don't want extra space at the top of a paragraph:

```
<p>
<br/>
Some Text
</p>
```

But not this one:

```
<p>
Some Text
<br/>
Some more text
</p>
```

This code, unfortunately, catches both:

```
p br:first-child {
   display: none;
}
```

How do I get it to catch only leading `<br>` tags? CSS3 is fine. I don't need to support dead horses.

Comment: `<br />` is not the same as whitespace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Unfortunately](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#first-child) this is not possible using only css. `first-child` doesn't take into account regular text, but worse still, your first example, just like the second, *does* have a text element before the `<br/>`, it's just empty space.

If you absolutely have to do this in the client-side, the only way I can think is to use some clever javascript ([jQuery](http://jquery.com/) is probably the easiest) to remove the unwanted `br` tags.